# Why does this MEX function create unexpected results?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am studying the book [Accelerating MATLAB Performance](https://goo.gl/8t3SeU) and on [page 394](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9oqZBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA394&dq=printf%28s%28%29%20called%20with%20%25d%20inputs,%25d%20outputs%5Cn,name,nrhs,nlhs%29;&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO2diojr7LAhXGZA8KHZepAx8Q6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q=printf%28s%28%29%20called%20with%20%25d%20inputs%2C%25d%20outputs%5Cn%2Cname%2Cnrhs%2Cnlhs%29%3B&f=false), this code is written:

```
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction (int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],/*outputs*/
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])/*inputs*/
{
    const char *name = mexFunctionName();
    printf("s() called with %d inputs,%d outputs\n",name,nrhs,nlhs);
}
```

based on what is said in the book, after building the MEX code with the command `mex hello.cpp`, the following results should be produced:

```
>> hello
hello() called with 0 inputs, 0 outputs
>> hello(1,2,3)
hello() called with 3 inputs, 0 outputs
>> [a,b] = hello(1,2,3)
hello() called with 3 inputs, 2 outputs
One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "hello".
```

But when I run the same code on my `Win7x64` machine, the results are as followed:

```
>> mex hello.cpp
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010'.
MEX completed successfully. 
>> hello
s() called with 2082650752 inputs,0 outputs
>> hello(1,2,3)
s() called with 2082650752 inputs,3 outputs
>> [a,b] = hello(1,2,3)
s() called with 2082650752 inputs,3 outputs
One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "hello".
```

What's the cause of these unexpected results?

Comment: The link above did not show me the page, but going via search the page is accessible: https://goo.gl/dGg5HA The code example in the book is wrong.

Comment: Following [the errata](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/books/matlab-performance) it is unknown to the author, I have send him a message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
printf("s() called with %d inputs,%d outputs\n",name,nrhs,nlhs);
```

you have 3 arguments but only two "%", so it outputs
"s() called with [name] inputs, [nrhs] output"
and nlhs is not used. Just remove name, and use instead

```
printf("s() called with %d inputs,%d outputs\n",nrhs,nlhs);
```

or use %s to display the function name:

```
printf("%s called with %d inputs,%d outputs\n",name,nrhs,nlhs);
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for alerting me - this was a typo that was entered during the book's editing phase - the correct code is `printf('%s() called...`  (i.e., the leading `%` was dropped by mistake). I will update the errata list accordingly.

I hope that you find the rest of the book useful. If you do, then please [post a positive comment on Amazon](http://amazon.com/Accelerating-MATLAB-Performance-speed-programs/product-reviews/1482211297/ref=cm_cr_dp_see_all_summary).

Comment: It's really a great book. Specially chapter 9 was really useful for me. Coul you please have a look at my code [here](http://goo.gl/wiscLt) and give me some ideas?